# Calculating arc length

Tags: calculus

I need to compute the arc length of the curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for $x(t)=(3t \cos t, 2t \sin t, 4t)$

I differentiated each component and I wanted to calculate the norm. However, I get a complicated expression which seems unlikely to integrate.

Please help

We have $v(t)=(3 \cos t -3t \sin t)\mathbf{i}+(2 \sin t+ 2t \cos t)\mathbf{j} +4\mathbf{k}$

Hence: the norm is $\sqrt{(3 \cos t -3t \sin t)^2+(2 \sin t+ 2t \cos t)^2 +4^2}$

I need to compute the arc length such that $0\leq t \leq a$

Comment: Show us your work.

Comment: What are your starting and ending values of $t$? That's pretty important to know.

Comment: @Carpodiem: you can use numerical integration if it is too complicated to get a closed form result.

Comment: I don't know the values of t

Comment: @Carpediem: Then just write it as an indefinite integral and you are done.

Comment: Your expression for $v(t)$ is incorrect.  It should be $v(t)=(3\cos t-3t\sin t)\hat{i}+(2\sin t+2t\cos t)\hat{j}+4\hat{k}$.

Comment: @Amzoti what do you mean?

Comment: @Carpediem: If you knew the starting and ending value of t, how would you show your result to find the actual length? You don't know those values, so what is a way you can show the length without those limits?

Comment: @Carpediem Assuming the domain of $x$ is $[0,2\pi \textbf{]}$, Amzoti meant for you to just let it be $$s_x(t)=\int _0 ^{2\pi} \sqrt{(3 \cos t -3t\ sin t)^2+(2 \sin t+ 2t \cos t)^2 +4^2}dt$$ without further simplification.

Comment: It is quite rare to find curves that have a closed-form formula for arclength. So, giving the answer as an integral seems reasonable. Alternatively, you could find the value of the integral by numerical methods, but that's probably not what you're being asked to do.

Comment: @GitGud I need to calculate it between 0 and a where a is an arbitrary real number

Comment: @Carpediem I don't know to do it, sorry. Also people suggest it can't done explicitly so just leave it as an integral from $0$ to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite rare to find curves that have a closed-form formula for arclength -- you usually end up with a big mess for which you can't find an anti-derivative. So, giving the answer as an integral seems reasonable. Alternatively, you could find the value of the integral by numerical methods, but that's probably not what you're being asked to do.